# How do i get ServletContext object in a simple class file?

Tags: java, servlets

I am creating a simple web application. I need to get reference to ServletContext object in that class. How can i get it?

Comment: Please just pass it in. Don't go for the worse option. What exactly do you need it for? What methods would you like to invoke on it? There must be better ways to achieve this.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You'd better pass it as argument to the constructor of your object, or set it using a setter method.

In fact, you may obtain the context attribute that is relevant to your object and pass only it via constructor/setter. For example:

```
YourClass obj = 
    new YourClass((AnotherClass) servletContext.getAttribute("yourAttribute"));
```

---

A much worse and more complication option is to:

1. Create a `ServletContextListener`
2. register it in web.xml with `<listener><listener-class></listener-class></listener>`
3. on `contextInitialized(..)` get the `ServletContext` from the event and store it in a singleton - a static field somehwere.

Alternatively, you can do this on each request, using a `ServletRequestListener` and store it in a `ThreadLocal` instead.

Then you can obtain the value via calling your singleton/threadlocal holder like this:

```
ServletContextHolder.getCurrentServletContext()
```

Comment: Or pass into a constructor a copy/view of `ServletContext` relevant to the object in question.

Comment: maybe Tom meant that you should obtain the context attribute that is relevant to the object and pass only it. I'll include it.

Comment: @BalusC I mean the relevant pieces from `ServletContext`, not the whole thing. It is a design error for a "simple class" to know about the servlets.

Answer (score -1):

I had this issue, but since I had called the class from a JSP, I simply passed the HttpServletRequest "request" reference from the JSP to the class and made the call in the class to:

```
String appPath = request.getServletContext().getRealPath("");
```