# issue with having java in a tomcat servlet edit a .txt file

Tags: java, apache, jakarta-ee, tomcat

Hey guys I am trying to have my code, once run through; it will insert into a .txt document that is already made, in the WebContent directory.  I am running in Apache Tomcat v7.0 - building in Eclispe.

CODE:

```
  public static void insertWinner(String winner) throws IOException{

        String filename= "Winner.txt";
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(filename,true); //the true will append the new data
        fw.write("Winner is" + winner);//appends the string to the file
        fw.close();

    }
```

This is being done inside a java file called BandIO which the servlet BandListServ.java calls on to insert a string value into the above code.

Nothing happen when I do this, not to sure why either.

Let me know if you need anyother info, Thanks again!

EDIT

I change it to this -

```
public static void insertWinner(String winner) throws IOException{


        FileWriter out = new FileWriter("Winner.txt");
        out.write("Hello");
        out.close();
        out = new FileWriter("Winner.txt", true);
        out.write(", world!");
        out.close();

    }
```

EDIT:

Okay so I tried this inside the servlet file but no cigar..

```
             response.setContentType("text/html");


             String filename = "Winner.txt";

             ServletContext context = getServletContext();


             InputStream is = context.getResourceAsStream(filename);
             if (is != null) {
                 InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
                 BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
                 PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
                 String text = "Winner is";


                 while ((text = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                     writer.println(text);
                 }
             }
```

Answer (score 2):

In principle access to the file system is done with

```
File file = getServletContext().getRealPath("/Winner.txt");
```

This file could be null, namely when the web application is deployed as .war (so zip format), and the web server is not configured to unpack the war.

In your case a file could have a concurrency problem, needing some locking. Maybe you should use a database table.

Also on next deployment the file might get lost.

Comment: Well I am just trying to access the file through a .java file that is not the servlet itself so the getServletContext() does not work...

Comment: But one cannot use a relative path, and the web content directory is known only via the ServletContext. You could configure a hard full path in a properties file for instance.

Comment: You need to pass object reference of `ServletContext` to that method. Take a look at SO thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728877/how-do-i-get-servletcontext-object-in-a-simple-class-file

Comment: In the last edit `InputStream is = new FileInputStream(context.getRealPath("/Winner.txt"));`