# JavaEE7 (GF4) @Inject ServletContext context returns java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, glassfish, cdi

I am newbie in CDI, maybe I am doing something wrong. [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/cdi-adv004.htm) it says that it's possible to inject ServletContext. So I have the following code:

```
public class ComponentInitializator {

@Inject 
private ServletContext context;

public void initialize(){...}
}
```

But it returns java.lang.NullPointerException. How can it be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ServletContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html)- defines a set of methods that a servlet uses to communicate with its servlet container. This resource will be injected on Servlet. Make your `ComponentInitializator` class as `Servlet` than try to access `ServletContext`.

```
  @WebServlet("/ComponentServlet")
  public class ComponentInitializator extends HttpServlet{
    @Inject
    private ServletContext context;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) 
                      throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out=resp.getWriter();
        out.println(context);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes, you are right. But what should I do if I don't want this class to be a servlet?

Comment: This may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728877/how-do-i-get-servletcontext-object-in-a-simple-class-file

Comment: But, @Inject may not be work for ServletContext without Web Component (Servlet, JSF etc).

Comment: There is no meaming in DI in servlet for ServletContext as there is a method getServletContext(). Therefore it is not obvious that it  planned to be used only in web components...

Answer (score 0):

Afaik it should work.

This module is pretty lean though so it might be easier to use that and spare yourself the trouble:

http://deltaspike.apache.org/servlet.html